# YYWW date format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a new date type in Excel which consisting of 4 digits. First two digit stands for year and other two stands for week numbers.

For example, if I want to express week 43 of 2023. I write as W2343.

Problem is, when I write W2343 to a cell (e.g A1) and add one more week on it (e.g =A1+1) it increases one week but when week reaches to 52 it doesn't be W2401 it keeps going like W2352, W2353, W2354, W2355 etc.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: What is your current solution? (I mean, how does excel know you're talking about weeks?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates in excel are numeric values. For example today's numeric value is `45226`. What you see as date are format types. In normal behaviour it's expected for you to get `W2351, W2352, W2353` etc. Because excel doesn't have this kind of date format.

What you can do is, use string parse and concatenation formulations to convert related numbers to desired date format.

---

**Solution:**

First of all your values must be numeric. we will add `W` character as cell format.

Let's say you have some values `2351, 2352, 2353` and entered from `A1:A3`.

So enter below formula to `B2` and pull down formulas for below cells.

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1;2))=53;(VALUE(LEFT(A1;2))+1)*100+1;A1+1)
```

Your date will be increased as expected after week `52`.

Your final table will look like below.

```
+-------+---------+
| Value | Formula |
+-------+---------+
|  2351 |   2352  |
+-------+---------+
|  2352 |   2353  |
+-------+---------+
|  2353 |   2401  |
+-------+---------+
```

As you see when formula finds week `53` it parses date string to `year` and `week`. Increases `year` value and updates `week` value then keep increasing for rest of weeks.

For showing `W`before your value go to `Format Cell -> Custom` and type `W#`.

Comment: How to use this formula vertically it looks complex for me

Comment: Same just paste formula to `A2` cell and it should work